# How to write some test cases to validate SPI driver working in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, spi

I Want to write few test cases related to SPI driver validation in linux. So if anyone is having any idea regarding it please suggest me. Or give some example so that I can start writing test cases.
How to validate SPI driver using linux command.

Comment: There is already tool, look at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/spi for the details.

Comment: Thanks andriy for your response. I had already gone through this link but there I saw only 3-4 APIs. My requirement is like to test SPI interface using some linux command. Like from root prompt I want to send some command over SPI interface, How I will do it?

Comment: You can do it based on `spidev_test` tool. look at its source code. Btw, *command* is not clear, what do you mean by that? SPI operates on words (usually 4-32 bits long) there is no commands.

Answer (score 0):

Inside linux kernel, Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c is a test code to do spi read/write from userspace(application level).

To use this feature, you need to enable the below parameter in kernel .config file.

```
CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV=y
```

If your kernel support dts entry then add the following too:

```
spidev2:spi@1 {
                    #address-cells = <1>;
                    #size-cells = <1>;
                    compatible = "rohm,dh2228fv";
                    spi-max-frequency = <30000000>;
                    reg = <0>;
            };
```

Comment: Hi Rahul thanks for your response. Is there is any way to test the SPI using some linux command. Like from root prompt I want to send some command over SPI interface, How I will do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use tools/spi/spidev_test.c to check spidev (just spidev)

Compile

> spi/spidev_test.c

, after use comand

> ./<file.o>-D /dev/spidev1.1

Attention! :

> reg = <0>;